# Using JQuery Datepicker To Only Show Months

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm looking to be able to use the [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to allow a user to select a particular month, without the option to select a particular day in that month. The forward and previous buttons on the Datepicker would take the user to different *years*, instead of different *months*.

The format that appears in the Datepicker textbox needs to be `mm/yyyy`. How can this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could do this:

```
$("#somedate").datepicker( { dateFormat: "mm/yy" } );
```

Or look here since you're question has been asked before:

[In search of JavaScript Month Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195768/in-search-of-javascript-month-picker)

Answer (score 1):

Why not making 2 dropdowns with months and year? something like:

```
var Months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September",  "October","November","December"];
var $selM = $('<select />');
$.each(Months,function(ind,item){

    $selM.append($('<option />').val(ind + 1).text(item));
});
$('span#Months').append($selM);
```

as for year you can get the current year by :

```
var now = new Date();
var year        = now.getYear();
```

then making another DDL for years with the range that you'd like to.