# Is there a jQuery month picker that mimics the Windows month picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm looking for a month picker jQuery plugin that mimics the Windows style month picker shown below...
[image: Windows style month picker]

I've seen the customizations to the jQuery UI datepicker that simply remove the days portion of the control.  However, I need something that resembles the plugin above.

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this, or a way to customize the existing jQuery UI datepicker to do so?

Comment: Hiya, Have you tried - Datepicker with - dateFormat: 'MM yy' - that might help. OR possibly try this http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/monthpicker -- && -- - this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943012/using-jquery-datepicker-to-only-show-months (Not the windows style though, closest is the datepicker plugin probably with a tweak. hope it helps man. cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tats_innit.  The 'MM yy' format string does give me the date in the format I need, but unfortunately it doesn't give me the UI that I need.  I'll take a look at the plugin that you mentioned, however, that may be a good option for us.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've tried dateFormat: 'yy/mm', and there are problems with it, for example, if you select a date, it will select the correct year and month and display that in the textbox, but then reopening the datepicker defaults back to the original value, and not the currently selected month.

Answer (score 1):

You can try
[jQuery.mtz.monthpicker](http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Period Selector can be a good solution for your question: http://tinytools.codesells.com/PeriodSelector