# jQuery datepicker display year month only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using datepicker to select year-month only. I filter out the day part like so:

```
$(el).datepicker( 
{changeMonth: true, 
changeYear: true, 
dateFormat:'yymm' } 
);
```

The code comes from the dataInit option in jqGrid.
When the user clicks in a day only the year-month is passed back to the input box.

**Is there any way to just show months where the days are?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This [code](http://thiamteck.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-month-and.html) is working flawlessly for me:

```
$(function()
{   
    $(".monthPicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
        }
    });

    $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
        });
    });
});

<label for="month">Month: </label>
<input type="text" id="month" name="month" class="monthPicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not tied to the datepicker plugin, you could use one of the "monthpickers" that are available, like this one: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/monthpicker.

(Edit) there's also a previous discussion here: [In search of JavaScript Month Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195768/in-search-of-javascript-month-picker).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion. I guess it is what I expected, there is no month picker functionality in datepicker. The other project does not have the same look and feel that I need on my current project. I guess I am going to have to look at adding this functionality myself.

Answer (score 0):

the tweaks over jQuery api tend to break on new releases. They're not working for me anymore, so I wrote a jQuery widget for that. Please check it out: http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker