# Jquery Monthpicker not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I found date picker in Jquery is there any tool to select only the months from the calendar searched alot and got the following code but its not working displays and error "Object doesnot support this property or method". The code is as follows

```
$('.monthpicker').monthpicker({
        'monthNames': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    })
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195768/in-search-of-javascript-month-picker

Comment: any online sample or demo ?!! why you use a simple combo box?!!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modifications in jqueryUI date picker.This can be done by hiding the calendar via some CSS trick.

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/33zwv/